# Can a rice cooker be used to evaporate remove all water in a soup?

Tags: water, rice-cooker

Suppose I cooked a soup and now wanted to evaporate/remove all water from the soup leaving behind fat, oil, minerals etc.  Could I place the soup liquid in a rice cooker, switch it on and expect it to have the desired result?  If not why not?

Is there an alternate device I can use to get the intended result?

Comment: Fuzzy logic cooker? I use mine to cook down and caramelize onions for onion soup. Not much water left by the time they are good and browned. It takes 3-4 cycles on fast cook to get there, as the cooker's over-temp sensor kicks in before any thing can be burnt, or *really* caramelized like I like it for onion soup.

Comment: Is this just broth? No solid ingredients, no meat, vegetables, grains, etc? Or if there are solid ingredients, what do you want to happen to them?

Comment: @Jefromi Basically the soup\stew would have already been cooked prior to adding to the rice cooker.  I could remove solids or keep them.  I just want to remove the water from the oils and fats. if removed from solid food surface then great but its no so important as I imagine any water has already poured into the base liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, you want to remove *all* the water from your soup? In other words, you want to make dehydrated soup powder, or a solid disk of dehydrated soup crust, out of your homemade soup?

The way I understand rice-cookers to work is they shut off as the temperature begins to climb above that of boiling water. Pretty sure that the temperature at the bottom of your soup would begin to climb above the shut-off level before the point where absolutely all water was removed from the rest of the pot. Judging from what happens on the stovetop when you burn your soup, it heats unevenly, and the bottom scorches while there is still plenty of liquid on top.

Even when your rice-cooker cooks rice, it doesn't remove *all* the water from the rice. So perhaps if you started with soup, the rice-cooker might possibly make a pretty good condensed soup concentrate (?). ...On the other hand I wouldn't count on it.